# How to override Logger.Error method in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, overriding

I am trying to call overidden error method in OverrideLogErrorMethod of Csfbs  class as follows

```
namespace IQCs
{
public class Csfbs
{
 public static string OverrideLogErrorMethod(string Name)
 {
   ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(LOGFILENAME);
   try
   {
     /*Somecode*/
      if (Name != "Name")
         throw new Exception();
      else
         return "success";
    }
    catch 
    {           
       Logger.Error("Overrided logger.error method");//here I want to call overriden error method
       return "override Success";
     }
  }
}

 public abstract class CustomLoggerClass: ILogger //Implementing Ilogger interface which implements error method
 {
    public abstract void Error(string message);
 }
public class CUs : CustomLoggerClass
{
   //Overriden error method in CUs
    public override void Error(string message)
    {           
        string messageInfo = "Control is in overrided Logger.error method";
        ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(LOGFILENAME);
        Logger.Info(messageInfo);
    }
 }
}
```

Control is not going to overridden error method, what changes in the code will make control to go to overriden error method? I dont want to change the name of the method as the name is used in many places

Comment: Does Logmanager.GetLogger return an instance of CUs?  It needs to for your code to work

Answer (score 2):

Create your own extension method.

It must be defined in a static class, and be a static method. E.g.

Definitions:

```
public static class Log4NetExtensions
{
    public static void MySpecialError(this Log log, string details, string message, Exception exception)
    {
        //Do something with parameters
    }
}
```

Use:

```
Log.MySpecialError(details, message, ex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement your own version of ILogger (you have it to a certain extend) and swap the injected functionality by means of DI configuration.

So instead of calling getLogger, you'd be injecting slightly different implementation that would contain your own logic. Additionally, it would be a better approach in terms of separation of concerns.